# How can i get first video thumbnail of playlist by API V3?

Tags: youtube-api

I am using google youtube API v3 to get playlist details by playlist id but in result it is showing second video thumbnail.

Do you have any idea How can i get first video thumbnail?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list

Comment: Please share your code what you have tried so far.

Comment: you can test at right side box at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list

Comment: you can use any playlist id and see result and check images